# Does the Monero default client deduct the fee from the sent amount?

Tags: transaction-fees

Will the transaction fee be automatically added when I transfer some moneros with the default wallet (client) i.e.:

2 XMR to be transferred

### + 0.01 fees (depending on speed and obfuscation level)

2.01 are used from my balance

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you transfer monero, you also pay the miner fee. This fee is also taken from your inputs, so if you transfer an amount A, then you end up with this:

N inputs, totalling X, such that X >= A + F
I outputs, totalling X-F
One of these I outputs is A
Change is X-F-A

So you spend A+F.

It would be confusing if you sent some amount, but the recipient would receive some slightly smaller amount.

Note that this is how the monero-wallet-cli and monero-wallet-gui wallets behave, so another wallet may well decide to it otherwise.

There is an exception to this rule: the sweep command family. sweep_all tries to send all your balance, but since you wouldn't have anything left for the fee, it sends all your balance minus the fee.

Comment: Hi, is there a setting to automatically add the fee to the amount to be transferred like in btcore client? Problem is: cannot see the fee to be added to the amount to be transfered.

Comment: There is no such setting. You can see the fee since the wallet tells you what it's about to do (if you have always-confirm-transfers set, it will then ask you to confirm or cancel).